# How to prevent the Images from. getting rebuild?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im fetching Images from firebase and Im using cached Network Images,
when the images got fetched and navigating to another page and come back the images reload again and so on.

this is the chached im using

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                   imageUrl:ProductModelsvar.imageUrl,
                   imageBuilder: (context,imageProvider)=>Container(

                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       image: DecorationImage(
                         image: imageProvider,
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   placeholder: (context,url)=>Container(
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child:  LoadingManegar(isLoading: true),
                   ),

                 ),
```

Comment: Try running app in release mode, it happens in debug mode only. In release build if you cache your image, it won't be rebuild

Comment: it is on release mode

Comment: @SuMit Same thing is happening to me, does not matter debug or release mode.